# Authentication with GitLab to a terminal

Tags: python-2.7, flask, oauth-2.0, gitlab

I have a terminal that served in webbrowser with wetty. I want to authenticate the user from gitlab to let user with interaction with the terminal(It is inside docker container. When user authenticated i ll allow him to see the containers terminal).

I am trying to do OAuth 2.0 but couldn't manage to achieve.

That is what i tried.

1. I created an application on gitlab.
2. Get the code and secret and make a http call with python script.
3. Script directed me to login and authentication page.
4. I tried to get code but failed(Their is no mistake on code i think)

Now the problem starts in here. I need to get the auth code from redirected url to gain access token but couldn't figure out. I used flask library for get the code.

```
from flask import Flask, abort, request
from uuid import uuid4
import requests
import requests.auth
import urllib2
import urllib

CLIENT_ID = "clientid"
CLIENT_SECRET = "clientsecret"
REDIRECT_URI = "https://UnrelevantFromGitlabLink.com/console"


def user_agent():

    raise NotImplementedError()

def base_headers():
    return {"User-Agent": user_agent()}


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    text = '<a href="%s">Authenticate with gitlab</a>'
    return text % make_authorization_url()


def make_authorization_url():
    # Generate a random string for the state parameter
    # Save it for use later to prevent xsrf attacks
    state = str(uuid4())
    save_created_state(state)
    params = {"client_id": CLIENT_ID,
              "response_type": "code",
              "state": state,
              "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,       
              "scope": "api"}
    url = "https://GitlapDomain/oauth/authorize?" + urllib.urlencode(params)
    print get_redirected_url(url)
    print(url)
    return url


# Left as an exercise to the reader.
# You may want to store valid states in a database or memcache.
def save_created_state(state):
    pass
def is_valid_state(state):
    return True

@app.route('/console')
def reddit_callback(): 
    print("-----------------")
    error = request.args.get('error', '')
    if error:
        return "Error: " + error
    state = request.args.get('state', '')
    if not is_valid_state(state):
        # Uh-oh, this request wasn't started by us!
        abort(403)
    code = request.args.get('code')
    print(code.json())
    access_token = get_token(code)
    # Note: In most cases, you'll want to store the access token, in, say,
    # a session for use in other parts of your web app.
    return "Your gitlab username is: %s" % get_username(access_token)

def get_token(code):
    client_auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    post_data = {"grant_type": "authorization_code",
                 "code": code,
                 "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI}
    headers = base_headers()
    response = requests.post("https://MyGitlabDomain/oauth/token",
                             auth=client_auth,
                             headers=headers,
                             data=post_data)
    token_json = response.json()
    return token_json["access_token"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=True, port=65010)
```

I think my problem is on my redirect url. Because it is just an irrelevant link from GitLab and there is no API the I can make call.

If I can fire

> @app.route('/console')

that line on Python my problem will probably will be solved.

I need to make correction on my Python script or different angle to solve my problem. Please help.

Comment: where is your server hosted ? localhost or accessible from the cloud ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was totally miss understand the concept of auth2. Main aim is to have access_token. When i corrected callback url as localhost it worked like charm.